# Is it mandatory to club all DS160's?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

Below is my situation. I am on H1B in US. While I was processing H1B for me I had processed H4 for my kid and it was approved. But, she couldn't come with me and that petition is expired now. I got a new petition and extension on H1B.
The problem here is now, my husband wants to bring my kid on B2(tourist) visa. 
He has filled a new DS160 for B2 and while making an appointment for PA with USCIS system says "Your personal details match the profile which already exists in our database." It is asking us to merge both the DS160's.

Should we consider old DS160 also ?Old one was for H4 and new for B2. 
How will this work ? Any help is really appreciated !!

Comment: Just to be clear--neither your husband nor child plan to stay in the US beyond the B-2 visa expiration date, correct?

Comment: @mkennedy visa expiration date is irrelevant.  What matters most is the purpose of the visit, along with the fact that B-2 visitors can be admitted for no more than one year (while six months is the normal period of admission).

Comment: @phoog sorry. My question to the OP was unclear. OP, your husband and child will not be doing a change of status (change visa type) when in the US, correct?

Comment: They will return to home country before expiration date and no intention to change the Visa type.